# Uploading images to Google Drive using Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, google-drive-api, cloud, file-sharing

Making an iOS application using Xamarin and would like to know if there is a way to save images to google drive or one drive. The GoogleDrive API was deprecated last year and is no longer an option, so I'm not sure if it's even possible. I want to try something but I can seem to find any information on the matter.

Any pointers? I need a free cloud service to use and that Xamarin supports. Or maybe I can make a stored procedure that can upload my images from the database to a cloud service?

Any help on the matter is appreciate

Comment: Google drive still has an active API - https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk.  There are thousands of storage services you could pick from.  AWS, Azure, etc

Comment: @Jason yes they do have an api but as stated in my question it is unfortunately not supported by Xamarin https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Drive.v3/

Comment: it's a REST API, of course you can use it in Xamarin.  Just because it doesn't have a pre-built Xamarin client doesn't mean that you can't use it.

Comment: Perhaps you are right. I'm not all that well versed with using API's. But in the google drive documentation it relies on the google drive library you have to include in your project (Which is now deprecated). This is what I was looking at when I came to that conclusion (view step 2): https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet

Comment: If you don't want to learn how to use the REST API, there are numerous other options available, as I pointed out in my first comment.

Comment: http://rest-examples.chilkat.io/google_drive/csharp/default.cshtml

Comment: I'd be fine learning something new of course, I just didn't know I could use their rest API without using that library they had listed in their documentation. I'll try something out in the links you provided and if I run into something I can't figure out I'll come back for guidance

Comment: @Jason I just can't find enough documentation for this. I can't get past the "enabling the api" feature on the website. API's are the way to go but I literally can't find a starting point

Comment: have you contacted their support?  Enabling a feature on their website is not really a programming issue SO can help with.  Using a REST API in Xamarin/C# is **extensively** documented.  I just posted a link with dozens of example queries for their REST API using C#.